# How do I pass selected values from drop down during on click on Next button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How do I pass selected values from drop down during on click on `Next` button and display in next screen with multiline text area.

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Multiselect from 'multiselect-react-dropdown';

const options = [
  { key: 'Axe', id: 1 },
  { key: 'Bags', id: 2 },
  { key: 'Coat', id: 3 },
  { key: 'Drum', id: 4 },
];

const NominatePerson = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="navbar-nav">
        <div className="leftNavItem">
          <a>
            <Link to={'/dashboard'} className="nav-link">
              {' '}
              <b>Dashboard</b>{' '}
            </Link>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h1>Nominate Person</h1>
      <div className="nomineeSelectBox">
        <Multiselect options={options} displayValue="key" showCheckbox={true} />
      </div>
      <div className="nominateButton">
        <input type="button" value="Next" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NominatePerson;
```

`nominationdetails.js`

```js
const NominationDetails = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      // How can i get the selected name here with text area displaying for each
      selected item ? // example: If I have selected two names from select box,
      on click on Next button it should display name and text area below each
      name.
    </div>
  );
};

export default NominationDetails;
```

`App.js`

function App() {
return (

```
          <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
          <Route path='/nominate/:token' component={Nominate} />
          <Route path='/nominatePerson' component={NominatePerson} />
          <Route path='/nominationdetails' component={Nomination Details} />
          <Route path='/errorPage/' component={ErrorPage} />
          <Route path='*' component={PageNotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
```

);
}

Answer (score 0):

[This section of multiselect-react-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiselect-react-dropdown#user-content-5-ref-as-a-prop-) seems to give what you want. Here's an example of how to use it:

```js
const NominatePerson = () => {
    multiselect = useRef();

    onNominate = () => {
        const items = multiselect.getSelectedItems();
        // ...
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            
            <div className="navbar-nav">
            
                <div className="leftNavItem">
                    <a><Link to={'/dashboard'} className="nav-link"> <b>Dashboard</b> </Link></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1>Nominate Person</h1>
            <div className="nomineeSelectBox">
                <Multiselect options={options} 
                displayValue="key"
                showCheckbox={true}
                ref={multiselect}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="nominateButton">
                <input type="button" value="Next"
                 onClick={onNominate}/>
            </div>
            
            
        </div>

        
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How can i pass the selected value to next screen  ?

Comment: I don't know what the next screen is -- presumably another route? Perhaps you want to include the information as part of the URL?

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question, on click on Next button how can I pass the selected value to NominationDetails screen ? Say if I have selected two name from select box, on click on Next button  it should display names and text area below each names

Comment: I have updated the question, on click on Next button how can I pass the selected value to NominationDetails screen ? Say if I have selected two name from select box, on click on Next button it should display names and text area below each names –

Comment: You'll need to show how these two routes are connected together to the main app.  You could e.g. use state held at the top level that's set by one view and consumed by another.

Comment: Route details added

Comment: To send your selected values you have at least three ways. Either you send them as state property in the history push method (read react-router documentation) or you use a state management library such as Redux, Mobx and so on. Of course, you can send values to any place of your application through React.Context instead of above-mentioned ways.